# How to potty train a two year old?

Tags: potty-training

I'm not a mother, but my aunt is having trouble potty training my cousin. She's not talking very much yet and I don't believe the last methods (I potty trained her older sister with: But you don't want to mess up your pretty panties right?) are going to work. She isn't talking much and is just starting to respond to anything me say to her. I'm tired of having to change her diaper when she is nearly 3 years old so I would really appreciate any tips I can get. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, Alice, and welcome. Have you tried anything besides the pretty panties (a nice idea, btw)? Also, we have a lot of questions and answers with the tag "potty training". Those might help you as well.

Comment: The pediatrician or primary care doctor can be a very helpful resource for this, and can screen for any health or developmental problems that might be making this more of a challenge.

Comment: Aparente001 It's not that she can't go to the toilet or control it. it's just that she chooses not to, but thank you. And I will mention it to my aunt.

Comment: Anongoodnurse - I'm not sure what my aunt has tried at this point but I've tried talking to her about being a big girl now. I'll look at the potty training tags. thank you

Answer (score 1):

She'll be ready when she's ready.. Talk up how cute her big girl panties will be and set a deadline... Maybe like her next bday and tell her I'm that diapers are out and panties are in!

Answer (score 0):

I've just recently potty trained my daughter.  This is approach I took:-

1. Picked a suitable day (when we didn't have plan for a few days) and stopped her wearing nappies (diapers) during the day at all.  I just put knickers/panties on her.
2. Kept plenty of spare clothes nearby and carpet cleaner when at home.
3. Kept a potty close by all the time
4. Each time she had an accident I sat her on the potty afterwards.
5. Asked her every half an hour if she needs the potty.

After a few days she really got the hang of it and it's been about a month now and she is dry most of the time (very occasional accident) and can tell me in advance when she needs to go.

Hope this helps.